# How to have a list with bullets except first item

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list with bullets, but the first `li` I want without a bullet 
I can't figure out how I can just one item without a bullet

```
<ul>
    <li class="no_bullet"> item 0 </li>
    <li>item 1 </li>
    <li>item 2 </li>
    <li>item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this:

- using `first-child/first-of-type`, no need for extra markup (using class)

```css
li:first-child {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 0 </li>
  <li>item 1 </li>
  <li>item 2 </li>
  <li>item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

if you need to remove the bullet from just this specific list, then set a class to `ul` and do it like this:

```css
.list-no-bullet li:first-child {
  list-style: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-no-bullet">
  <li>item 0 </li>
  <li>item 1 </li>
  <li>item 2 </li>
  <li>item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the `list-style` property

```css
li:first-child {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 0</li>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

You can also replace `first-child` with `nth-child(index)`, if you want to select a specific item that isn't first or last, e.g.

```
li:nth-child(3) {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: why the second one ? :)

Comment: Updated for clarity, just included that as an example for getting at specific child elements

Answer (score 2):

To remove a bullet you would use `list-style: none`. There are a number of other valid styles you could also use including roman numerals, images and positioning of the bullet: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)

```css
.no_bullet {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="no_bullet"> item 0 </li>
  <li>item 1 </li>
  <li>item 2 </li>
  <li>item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I already tried that, but the problem with this solution is that it mess up what I already had.

Comment: Then you need to explain this in your question. We cant help if you only provide half of the problem.